# Loop over variable names, create new variable and assign values

Tags: r, loops, assign

I am trying to determine the mean of multiple vectors. Is there a more efficient alternative than using `assign` within a loop to calculate the means, as I do below?

```
a=c(1,2,3,4)
b=c(1,3,4,3,4)
c=c(3,9,4,2,7,3,7)
for (i in c("a","b","c")) {
  assign(paste(i,"mean", sep = ""), mean(get(i)))  
}
```

Comment: try `list2env('names<-'(lapply(list(a,b,c), mean), paste0(c('a', 'b', 'c'),'mean')),.GlobalEnv)` Although you should learn to work with lists to avoid this syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating a new variable for each vector you want to take the mean of, I would calculate and store the average of each vector together with something like:

```
means <- sapply(mget(c("a", "b", "c")), mean)
```

This returns a named vector of averages; the average of each variable can be accessed by name:

```
means["a"]
#   a 
# 2.5 
means["b"]
# b 
# 3 
means["c"]
# c 
# 5
```

Note that this will probably simplify the code you use after calculating the means. If you had `var <- "a"` indicating the variable you wanted to process, you can now get its mean with `means[var]` instead of needing to use something clunky like `get(paste0(var, "mean"))`.